# Sum every element in a range in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, math

I'm trying to make my small function work which adds every number together in a range.

For example when I call the method like: `sumAll(3,10)` it should do
`3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10`

It works if I give the function positive integers but if it receives a negative number or a string or an array for example, it doesn't work properly.. I just want to return "ERROR" if the supplied parameter is not a positive integer.

Can I have some help with this please? Is there a more elegant (better) way?

My code:

```
const sumAll = (...args) => {
    let max = Math.max(...args);
    let min = Math.min(...args);

    if ((min < 0) || (!Number.isInteger(min)) || (!Number.isInteger(max)) || (Array.isArray(...args))) {
        return "ERROR";
    }

    let n = (max - min) + 1;

    return ((max + min) * n) / 2;
}
```

Comment: why not `throw`?

Comment: Can you pls tell in which scenario this code is not working? For me

sumAll(3,10) // work fine
sumAll(-1,10) // return Error

And this is what is expected, no?

Comment: It didn't work when I was passing either a string, negative number or an array to the function

Comment: I would suggest you to retry your code, as for me it is working without any change as per you are saying. Otherwise Nina's code is what you can go ahead with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a gaussian formular for getting a count from 1 ... n and subtract the sub count.

For getting only a result if possible, you could add a check for positive integers.

```js
const
    isPositiveInt = v => Number.isInteger(v) && v > 0,
    sumN = n => n * (n + 1) / 2,
    range = (m, n) => isPositiveInt(m) && isPositiveInt(n)
        ? sumN(Math.max(m, n)) - sumN(Math.min(m, n) - 1)
        : 'ERROR';

console.log(range(3, 10));
console.log(range(10, 3));
console.log(range());
console.log(range(3));
console.log(range('', 10));
console.log(range(0.2, 0.3));
```

Comment: Definitely going to try but how would I make sure it throws an error if the parameter is not a positive int? I think thats the only part that doesn't work right now.